# I have issues with forwarding messages to my Telegram bot (that should be forwarded to groups)

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I'm on PHP and JS and use the simple Telegram API endpoints with cURL, no Framework.

The task is, "forward messages from allowed user_ids to groups you are member of" and everything worked fine until recently.
The problem now is, that forwarding does not stop anymore. It starts again and again.

I had a database version with some settings, the allowed users, also an automated greeting of new members with the help of OpenAI. Meanwhile I wrote the third version from scratch as I thought it is my fault or something changed in the update structure.

The code is dead simple and I actually do not want to post it here as I am sure it is not the problem. I have groups that work as test groups and it works perfectly. The test groups only have 2-5 users.
It loops through the group_ids and sends the message.

```
// Abrufen des Update-Payloads von Telegram
$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

// Überprüfen, ob ein Update vorhanden ist und ob es eine Nachricht enthält
if (isset($update['message'])) {
    // Überprüfen, ob der Absender in der Liste der erlaubten Benutzer-IDs enthalten ist
    if (in_array($update['message']['from']['id'], $allowedUserIds)) {
        // ist es eine Weiterleitung?
        if(isset($update['message']['forward_date']) || isset($update['message']['forward_from'])) {
            // Weiterleiten der Nachricht an die Zielgruppen
            $debug_message = forwardMessageToGroups($update['message'], $targetGroupIds);
            // debug
            $args = [
                'chat_id' => $debug_chat_id,
                'text' => json_encode($debug_message, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT),
                'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
            ];
            cUrl('sendMessage', $args);
        }
    } else {
        // Absender ist nicht autorisiert
        error_log('Unautorisierte Benutzer-ID: ' . $update['message']['from']['id']);
    }
}

function cUrl($action,$args = false) {

    global $telegram_url, $botToken;

    $full_url = $telegram_url . $botToken . '/' . $action;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $full_url);
    if($args) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($args));
    }

    $res = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_error($ch)) {
        $result['error'] = curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        $result['success'] = json_decode($res);
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    // var_dump($result);
    // return $result;

}
```

The bot is bound to a webhook and only reacts to allowed user_ids and only to forwarding messages. I have tested it again and again but cant find the issue as it is working perfectly with the test groups and sometimes also with the live groups.

The amount of live groups is around 50, but was 20 as it happened. The size of the groups is around 10 to 200.

Comment: Have you added some logging of the incoming requests first of all, to verify whether you might be getting the same updates multiple times? That is usually what happens with webhooks, when your system does not respond with a 200 OK response within a specified time frame, they will assume delivery failed, and make a couple more attempts to deliver the same payload.

Comment: Thanks. I do not have a logging of the incoming events but the behavior seem to reflect that issue. Actually it starts sending right away and has a sleep(3) between each group. I did that being unsure what the Telegram API will think if I immediately send so many messages at the same time.
I will dive into it.

Comment: Unfortunately the `error_log(print_r($_POST, true), 3, 'webhook.log');` only results in
`Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)`
Which is strange as the script **does** forward messages, but obviously gets called too often

Comment: No, nothing strange about that, because telegram sends you a `Content-Type: application/json` request, and for that content type PHP will _never_ populate $_POST. That's the reason you are reading your input data here like this in the first place, `$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);` So if you want to debug what's incoming, that is what you should log - `$update`. (Or, technically, if there was a chance that you might ever _not_ get valid JSON posted to this endpoint, rather the result of `file_get_contents('php://input')`.)